# Is there a way to fix this error in terminal: -bash: HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and just installed it following the instructions on [this website](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac).

I'm not sure why, but now whenever I open terminal, I get the following error message:

> -bash: HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory

Is there something I'm missing? As far as I can tell, Ruby is installed correctly and is running fine.

Comment: Most likely your `.bash_profile` is screwed up; include the rvm line in your question.

Comment: it might be that you've missed the '$' is HOME declaration ($HOME).

Comment: You can look this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795891/bash-home-xxx-rvm-scripts-rvm-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you put `HOME` in your .bash_profile instead of `$HOME`.  You should also verify that your .rvm directory exists in your home directory.  You could also check the value of $HOME by running `echo $HOME` in a shell, and it should return something like `/home/yourname`.

Note: You could change "$HOME" to "~".

Answer (score 0):

This maybe solve your problem:

Before you install RVM, you can input this in your terminal to check server key:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

Then you can input the following command to install rvm

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Just have a try~

Answer (score -1):

You must source the rvm scripts so that they are available to your terminal session

```
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

You may want to add it to your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file so that they are executed every time you load a terminal window like so:

```
$ echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> .bashrc
```