# bash: /home/XXX/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I just walk-through with the installation of Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu using RVM.

First I have logged in as the **root** user.

Then I started with the following commands.

1. `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails`

   It has been installed without any error.
2. `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

   When I run this command. It showing the error as **bash: /home/XXX/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory**

I added the `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` command in my **.bashr** file.

Comment: You likely don't want to be Root when you are doing this.  Unless you are positive this is the way you want to install RVM.  It changes how it works.  It is meant to be used and installed in normal user space.

Answer (score 24):

Install RVM:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

Now you will get a success message. Then, run this command:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

See http://rvm.io/ for more info.

Answer (score 12):

After installing rvm, try:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

If the above command throws some issue, try this command:

```
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Answer (score 11):

I think they may have moved some files around fixed with:

```
source /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Answer (score 6):

Firstly no need to go for sudo access while installing rvm, just follow the very basic commands below

```
   $\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

This will install rvm.

```
   $ rvm list known
   # MRI Rubies
   [ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
   [ruby-]1.8.7[-p374]
   [ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
   [ruby-]1.9.2[-p320]
   [ruby-]1.9.3[-p545]
   [ruby-]2.0.0-p353
```

Install a version of ruby as required.

```
   $ rvm install 2.0.0-p353
```

Now you can use the version of ruby for which you need to install rails as a gem.

```
   $ rvm use 2.0.0
```

Also you can make it default if you want so

```
   $ rvm use 2.0 --default
```

Next you can install rails as a gem.

```
    $ gem install rails
```

gems should never be installed with sudo access as they change from project to project. rvm helps in managing the different versions of ruby in one m/c. You can also use gemsets to isolate gems and specific versions from one application to another.

Answer (score 1):

just create ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm directories, then try to install rvm but make sure you are not logged in as root.

Answer (score 1):

This `source /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm` works for me on ubuntu 20.04.
I changed the **local** in `/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm` to **share**
I assume that you have installed the rvm.

Answer (score 0):

Is generally **not recommend** to install RVM as a root user because of umask security risk. Try running these commands as a user.

**Downloading RVM (Do not sudo this command)**

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

**Then you'll need to add the location to sources(You'll probably need to reload your bash for rvm to work)**

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

**You can install your desired version like so(replace ruby_version with one you would like to install, eg 2.1.4)**

```
rvm install ruby_version
```

**To list the available version on your machine**

```
rvm list
```

**To use a version of ruby run**

```
rvm use ruby_version
```

If you have any trouble refere to the [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) website

Comment: Error 

Downloading **https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/1.26.0.tar.gz**
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 861)


Could not download **'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/1.26.0.tar.gz'.**
  curl returned status '23'.


Downloading **https://bitbucket.org/mpapis/rvm/get/1.26.0.tar.gz**
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 15973)


Could not download **'https://bitbucket.org/mpapis/rvm/get/1.26.0.tar.gz'.**
  curl returned status '23'.

Comment: Looks like a permission error, or because you already tried to install via sudo there which my cause some problems. Does `env | grep rvm` output anything? in particular `rvm_path=` variable

Answer (score 0):

As root, you traditionally don't have a `/home` folder.  Root's home is different than a normal user.

You very likely don't want to install RVM as root.

Please do read the information at http://rvm.io specifically the installation notes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use sudo find to locate the correct path of the rvm directory? If you find the path, you should be able to rerun the source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm command with the correct path.

Also, I fully agree with the previous answers about not creating it as root. DigitalOcean was a pretty good tutorial on adding users https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Alright so when you get a failure message "No such file or directory",
type

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

in your terminal.
There will be a GPG signature verification failure.
Bellow that failure there would be a link for github and a key something like this

```
gpg2 --recv-keys 409B6B...
```

So download a tar file from the github link and run this code to install GPG:

```
sudo apt install gnupg2
```

and run that key :

```
gpg2 --recv-keys 409B6B...
```

next run the code:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

it will show you installing the rvm
and then you can run:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

thats it you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

If you install rvm via apt-get you can add the following line into ~/.zshrc or ~/.bashrc

```
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

For me all the above methods didn't workout.
After the installation and updates, still the terminal shows this "error bash: /root/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory"

The simple method which helps me to solve this error is :

1. **Show Hidden Files**
2. Go to the Home (where the bash scripts are stored)
3. Edit the **.bashrc**
4. At the bottom you can find some lines about **rvm**
   just **clear the rvm lines** and **save** the file.
5. Open terminal and check it.

Answer (score -1):

Your surest bet is to use home brew. Funny part is if you try brew upgrade ruby, you will have an error if brew wasn't used to install ruby in the first instance so use:

```
$ brew install ruby
```

Then afterwards use

```
$ brew upgrade ruby
```

You may need to close and reopen your terminal to see the effect of the upgrade by typing

```
$ ruby -v
```